# What part of the process virtual memory does Windows Task Manager display

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, ram

My question is a bit naive. I'm willing to have an overview as simple as possible and couldn't find any resource that made it clear to me. I am a developer and I want to understand what exactly is the memory displayed in the "memory" column by default in Windows Task Manager:

[image]

To make things a bit simpler, let's forget about the memory the process shares with other processes, and imagine the shared memory is negligible. Also I'm focussed on the big picture and mainly care for things at GB level.

As far as I know, the memory reserved by the process called "virtual memory", is partly stored in the main memory (RAM), partly on the disk. The system decides what goes where. The system basically keeps in RAM the parts of the virtual memory that is accessed sufficiently frequently by the process. A process can reserve more virtual memory than RAM available in the computer.

From a developer point of view, the virtual memory may only be partially allocated by the program through its own memory manager (with `malloc()` or `new X()` for example). I guess the system has no awareness of what part of the virtual memory is allocated since this is handled by the process in a "private" way and depends on the language, runtime, compiler... Q: **Is this correct?**

My hypothesis is that the memory displayed by the task manager is essentially the part of the virtual memory being stored in RAM by the system. **Q: Is it correct? And is there a simple way to know the total virtual memory reserved by the process?**

Comment: There is a tooltip shown if you hover over column caption. You may also switch to `Detail` tab and select columns of interest there. It has about 12 different memory metrics available.

Answer (score 3):

Memory on windows is... extremely complicated and asking 'how much memory does my process use' is effectively a nonsensical question. TO answer your questions lets get a little background first.

Memory on windows is allocated via `ptr = VirtualAlloc(..., MEM_RESERVE, ...)` and committed later with `VirtualAlloc(ptr+n, MEM_COMMIT, ...)`.

Any reserved memory just uses up address space and so isn't interesting. Windows will let you `MEM_RESERVE` terabytes of memory just fine. Committing the memory does use up resources but not in the way you'd think. When you call commit windows does a few sums and basically works out (total physical ram + total swap - current commit) and lets you allocate memory if there's enough free. BUT the windows memory manager doesn't actually give you physical ram until you actually use it.

Later, however, if windows is tight for physical RAM it'll swap some of your RAM out to disk (it may compress it and also throw away unused pages, throw away anything directly mapped from a file and other optimisations). This means your total commit and total physical ram usage for your program may be wildly different. Both numbers are useful depending on what you're measuring.

There's one last large caveat - memory that is shared. When you load DLLs the code, the read-only memory [and even maybe the read/write section but this is COW'd] can be shared with other programs. This means that your app *requires* that memory but you cannot count that memory against just your app - after all it can be shared and so doesn't take up as much physical memory as a naive count would think.

(If you are writing a game or similar you also need to count GPU memory but I'm no expert here)

All of the above goodness is normally wrapped up by the heap the application uses and you see none of this - you ask for and use memory. And its just as optimal as possible.

You can see this by going to the details tab and looking at the various options - commit-size and working-set are really useful. If you just look at the main window in task-manager and it has a single value I'd hope you understand now that a single value for memory used has to be some kind of compromise as its not a question that makes sense.

Now to answer your questions

Firstly the OS knows exactly how much memory your app has reserved and how much it has committed. What it doesn't know is if the heap implementation you (or more likely the CRT) are using has kept some freed memory about which it hasn't released back to the operation system. Heaps often do this as an optimisation - asking for memory from the OS and freeing it back to the OS is a fairly expensive operation (and can only be done in large chunks known as pages) and so most of them keep some around.

Second question: Dont use that value, go to details and use the values there as only you know what you actually want to ask.

EDIT:

For your comment, yes, but this depends on the size of the allocation. If you allocate a large block of memory (say >= 1MB) then the heap in the CRT generally directly defers the allocation to the operating system and so freeing individual ones will actually free them. For small allocations the heap in the CRT asks for pages of memory from the operating system and then subdivides that to give out in allocations. And so if you then free every other one of those you'll be left with holes - and the heap cannot give those holes back to the OS as the OS generally only works in whole pages. So anything you see in task manager will show that all the memory is still used. Remember this memory isn't lost or leaked, its just effectively pooled and will be used again if allocations ask for that size. If you care about this memory you can use the [crt heap statistics famliy of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library) to keep an eye on those - specifically `_CrtMemDumpStatistics`

Comment: Thanks. I used the word "commited" maybe informally. I'm not sure we mean the same. Imagine you do 2 millions of malloc(2). Then free one out of 2 living 1 millions holes. What I call "commited" is the 1 million left. Does the system really has an awareness of this?

Comment: @BenoitSanchez I've editted the answer which will hopefully be helpful, but tldr yes you're right - the OS doesn't know about the holes.

Comment: @MikeVine actually it sort of does, `HeapAlloc` is the base `malloc` of the system which is implemented on top of `VirtualAlloc`. `HeapAlloc` has a ['LowFragmentationHeap'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx) that it uses for small allocations and is very good at doing what it can to release pages no longer in use etc. Obviously that's pretty easy to break if you don't free enough for the entire page to get released.

Comment: @Mike. Ok. I see. Thanks. The text you added is very important for my understanding.

Comment: @Mgetz of course - if a whole page is free then the heap can release it back to the os - but with the usage pattern described here (allocate 1 million tiny objects, free every OTHER one back) then its highly likely, even with LFH, that each allocation is fairly sequential and so there are no whole free page just a lot of pages with about 50% usage.

Comment: @BenoitSanchez unless you're using a custom CRT generally it's all done directly through various incarnations of `HeapAlloc` or `RTLAllocateHeap`

Comment: @BenoitSanchez one last point before I go away, you've probably gathered from this answer that _commit_ has a very specific meaning when talking about memory management. I understand what you mean by commit (but it isn't the usual meaning) but dont know what its normal name would be.

Comment: Yep. I've updated my answer to remove the word "commit" especially because it created confusion with your answer. I said "allocated" since I don't know any better word...